# How do I redirect two wordpress pages to https?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, ssl, https

I have an SSL certificate installed on my website and I would like to redirect two specific pages to https, e.g. `http://domain.com/?page=credit and http://domain.com/?page=submit_form` to https.

My web host added the following code to my .htaccess file, above the Wordpress settings but it still doesn't redirect the pages:

```
Redirect /?page=credit https://domain.com/?page=credit

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)p=(credit)($|&)
RewriteRule (.*) https://domain.com/?page=credit [R=301,QSA,L]
```

I'm sorry I'm not too good at this. Any help I can get will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You might be interested in this: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/28395/11628

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)page=(credit|submit_form)(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)page=(credit|submit_form)(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thaks anubhava. It works but once I click on a link that is supposed to link to a normal http page, it still shows as https. Is there anything I can do to change it? Once again, thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Cool! Thanks so much. It works perfectly. The only thing left is that the SSL padlock icon has a red "X" on it and the browser reports that the page contains some unsecure items. Any idea on how I can overcome this? All my content is hosted on the site, with no external content. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: Also, I commented out the first line; Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews because it caused the site to go blank.

Comment: That red "X" is there because on a https page you are retrieving some resources (css, js or images) using unsecured http protocol.

Comment: Thanks a lot anubhava. I don't want to seem like too much of a bother but..is there something you could suggest for the resource retrieval? I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: For that you need to add little bit of logic thru your backend code which creates https page. Basically check what if current page is a secured one and if yes then include those resource using https.