# htaccess https redirect for 3 pages

Tags: .htaccess, https

I googled as well as try something similar to this
[How do I redirect two wordpress pages to https?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422709/how-do-i-redirect-two-wordpress-pages-to-https)

It's only working for the first page, checkout_form.  The other pages are not switching to https.  I want 3 pages to be https redirect.  checkout_form, bit coin, and paypal, all .php files to be https.

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com 
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# force certain pages to be https (secure)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond $1 ^(checkout_form|bitcoin|paypal) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com 
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# force certain pages to be https (secure)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (checkout_form|bitcoin|paypal) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NC]
```

Make sure to test in a new browser to avoid 301 caching issues.

Comment: Just like my code above, that redirects bit coin and paypal for a split second, and then kicks them back to http.

Comment: That is most likely due to permalonk settings in Wordpress. I am no WP expert but open your page in Firebug and see how many redirects happen.

Comment: My site is not wordpress.  Here are the live sites:

www.mathcelebrity.com/bitcoin.php

www.mathcelebrity.com/paypal.php

www.mathcelebrity.com/checkout_form.php

The last one works fine.

Comment: When I requested `http://www.mathcelebrity.com/bitcoin.php` it got redirected to: `https://www.mathcelebrity.com/bitcoin.php` Same thing happened to `www.mathcelebrity.com/paypal.php` also (got redirected to https). Can you test in a new browser?

Comment: Good point.  Chrome looks good.  Safari is the one that flashes https and then shows http.  I accepted the answer above.  Thanks again.

Comment: You can just delete all cache from safari and then it should behave fine.